# How would you solve the following Matrix Puzzle by u/---Kyu---?

Tags: pattern

I've been staring at this puzzle for too long, but I cannot get how it was solved.

Based on the comments in the thread, a user identified that Number 1 is the correct answer, with the comment by [u/---Kyu---](https://www.reddit.com/user/---Kyu---/) stating:

> Correct! it is a continuous pattern.

Can someone share how the pattern is derived?

([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/mensa/comments/e4bdxb/7_fun_puzzles_to_help_soothe_your_noodly_itch_d/))

[image: Kyu Puzzle Question 5]

Comment: I guess the answer is 1 shortly i'll come with explaination:)